# How to implement selenium framework using jQuery ? Any ideas?

Tags: jquery, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I want to implement my Selenium framework by using jQuery. Has anyone implemented this in java ?

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScriptExecutor you can create customise Locators based on JQuery here's a snippet that will give you an idea.

JavaScript Executor Doc
http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/index.html

JQueryFactory Docs and Project

http://alp82.github.io/abmash/doc/com/abmash/core/jquery/package-summary.html

https://github.com/alp82/abmash

```
   HtmlUnitDriver instanceDriver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3_6);
   instanceDriver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
   try {
   jQueryFactory jQuery = new jQueryFactory();
   jQuery.setJs(instanceDriver);

   instanceDriver.get("http://apple.com");
   jQuery.query("[name=q]").val("SeleniumJQuery").parents("form:first").submit();

    String searchQueries = jQuery.queryUntil("#resultStats:contains(searchQueries)").text();   
    System.out.println(searchQueries.split(" ")[1] + " results found!");
      } finally {
           instanceDriver.close();
           }
```